# Bash: file not created with '>' command

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, docker, docker-compose

I'm writing a script to create backups of a MySQL database running in a docker container. The database is correctly up and running.

My current code is

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/root/.local/bin:$PATH

docker-compose exec -T db mkdir -p /opt/booking-backup

docker_backup_path="/opt/booking-backup/dump_prod_$(date +%F_%R).sql"
copy_backup_path="/root/backup_scripts/booking_prod/dump_prod_$(date +%F_%R).sql"

docker-compose exec db mysqldump --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --user=root --password="pw" booking > "$docker_backup_path"
docker-compose exec db mysqldump --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --user=root --password="pw" booking > "/opt/booking-backup/dump_prod.sql"

[ -d ./backup ] || mkdir ./backup
docker cp $(docker-compose ps -q db):$docker_backup_path $copy_backup_path
```

However, when I execute it it throws this error:

```
Error: No such container:path: f0baa241becd20d2690bb901fb257a4bbec8cac17e6f1ce6d50adb9532bbae03:/opt/booking-backup/dump_prod_2019-05-28_14:23.sql
```

What makes this weirder is that I have the exact same code (but with `booking` switched out for `abc`, and with PSQL instead of MySQL) that works correctly.

It appears that this line

```
docker-compose exec db mysqldump --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --user=root --password="pw" booking > $docker_backup_path
```

does *not* create the output file, but when I use `tee` I can see the contents of the dump and they are correct.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell redirections

```
docker-compose exec db mysqldump ... > "$docker_backup_path"
docker-compose exec db mysqldump ... > "/opt/booking-backup/dump_prod.sql"
# -----------------------------------^ here
```

... will be expanded by your *local* shell, not inside the container. Meaning the files are written to your local filesystem not to the container's filesystem.

Comment: I just gave that a shot but I got this message: `docker cp /opt/booking-backup/dump_prod_2019-05-29_08:13.sql /root/backup_scripts/booking_prod/dump_prod_2019-05-29_08:13.sql
must specify at least one container source`
is there maybe a way to redirect the shell redirections to the docker container?

Comment: Nvm, I had a typo. What I want to say is: The files won't get created in the container, they will be created on your local system